Fetching data from server in Next.js
I am using server component to fetch data from the backend. I am getting the data back as I  tested using console.log . But the component is not looping through my data as they are not displayed in the table.
Here is the code.
import Link from 'next/link'
export default async function PatronsList() {
const result = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/patrons", { noCache: true })
if (!result.ok) {
    throw new Error("Error in fetching patrons");
}

const { patrons } = await result.json();

console.log(patrons)

return (
<div className="container my-5">
    <Link href="/dashboard/patrons/add" className="btn btn-success">New patron</Link>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Firstname</th>
                <th>Lastname</th>
                <th>Address</th>
                <th>Cardnumber</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Phone</th>
                <th>Edit</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            {patrons.map(p => {
                <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>{p.firstname}</td>
                <td>{p.lastname}</td>
                <td>{p.address}</td>
                <td>{p.cardnumber}</td>
                <td>{p.email}</td>
                <td>{p.phone}</td>
                <td><Link href="/dashboard/patrons/edit" className="btn btn-success">Edit</Link></td>
                </tr>
            })}



        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

)
}
It seems like the component is being returned before data is available.

You are missing the return statement in your map function
<tbody>
{patrons.map((p, index) => ( //return here
        <tr key={p.id || index}> //be sure to add key
          <td>{index + 1}</td>
          <td>{p.firstname}</td>
          <td>{p.lastname}</td>
          <td>{p.address}</td>
          <td>{p.cardnumber}</td>
          <td>{p.email}</td>
          <td>{p.phone}</td>
          <td>
            <Link href="/dashboard/patrons/edit" className="btn btn-success">Edit</Link>
          </td>
        </tr>
      ))}
</tbody>

